# JAXB chokes on UTF-16 XML

Tags: jaxb, utf

My project parses XML from various sources using JAXB. This works for most sources, but I am having trouble parsing documents from one particular source. The only difference I have been able to find is that the offending document reports its encoding to be UTF-16, whereas others sem to be in UTF-8 as far as I can tell.

Here is the code:

```
InputStream inputStream = new FileInputStream(inputFile);
DocumentBuilderFactory dbf = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance();
dbf.setNamespaceAware(true);
DocumentBuilder db = dbf.newDocumentBuilder();
Document doc = db.parse(inputStream);
```

This throws the following exception:

```
[Fatal Error] :1:40: Content is not allowed in prolog.
org.xml.sax.SAXParseException; lineNumber: 1; columnNumber: 40; Content is not allowed in prolog.
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.parsers.DOMParser.parse(DOMParser.java:257)
    at com.sun.org.apache.xerces.internal.jaxp.DocumentBuilderImpl.parse(DocumentBuilderImpl.java:339)
    at javax.xml.parsers.DocumentBuilder.parse(DocumentBuilder.java:121)
    at ... (my code)
```

The offending document starts with

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-16"?>
```

followed directly by the opening tag for the root element. I examined the file with a hex editor; there are no other characters (not even BOMs or any nonprinting characters) before the opening tag.

If I change the `encoding` attribute to `UTF-8`, the code runs past that point (though it throws an unrelated exception further down the line).

Is JAXB incompatible with UTF-16? Or what else is the problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Running `xmlstarlet fo` on the document produced the following error:

```
/path/to/document.xml:1.38: Document labelled UTF-16 but has UTF-8 content
```

**In conclusion, `org.xml.sax.SAXParseException` with the error message *Content is not allowed in prolog* is fairly unspecific and in some cases misleading**.

While **usually** it indicates that illegal extra characters (including nonprinting ones) were encountered before the root element, it may also indicate something completely different – such as the XML prolog specifying an encoding which does not match the actual encoding.